# How do you access the hard drive in ubuntu?

Tags: hard-drive

I just loaded Ubuntu to replace Windows. I am trying to load the sims 3 game, and it requires a 'no cd' file to be added to it. How do I access the hard drive to make changes to folders?

Comment: Have you installed the sims3 game using Wine or from the Steam client for Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Sims 3 is not designed to work on Ubuntu, according to their website it supports Mac and PC only.

If you are trying a workaround, please give details of what you are trying.

Otherwise, [this may help you](http://www.maketecheasier.com/play-the-sims3-in-linux/2010/11/18) get started if you have the time to try getting PC games working on linux.